# To find array with smallest length among multiple 1D arrays [PYTHON]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any inbuilt function in Python to achieve this, or i have to do this the traditional way.
E.g.

```
A1 = [1,2,3]
A2 = [1]
A3 = [1.2]
```

OUTPUT - A2

Comment: not a graceful one.  Generally, you should include variables in some kind of collection if you want to compare them: `d = [A1,A2,A3]` is a list of lists, then `min(d)` will work

Comment: Do you want a copy of the list or a reference?

Comment: any would be sufficient, copy or reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
A1 = [1,2,3]
A2 = [1]
A3 = [1.2]
print(min([A1,A2,A3],key=len))
```

**Output:**

```
[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
A1 = [1,2,3]
A2 = [1]
A3 = [1,2]
A = []
A = [A1, A2, A3] # make list of lists
min = 10000000 # some threshold 
for a in A: # iterate bigger list
    if(len(a) < min): # compare at each step
        min = len(a) # change value of min if condition is met
print(len(a)) # print reqd result
```

Output:

```
1
```